# Can I pipe stdout on one server to stdin on another server?

Tags: pipe, stdout, stdin

`stdout` on one CentOS server needs to be piped to `stdin` on another CentOS server. Is this possible?

### Update

ScottPack, MikeyB and jofel all have valid answers. I awarded the answer to Scott because, even though my question didn't specify security as a requirement, it's always nice to be safe. However, the other two fellows' suggestions will also work.

Comment: It's worth noting that the (only) major advantage of the non-ssh approach is throughput speed; if you're on a fast network and security is unnecessary this may be worth the extra inconvenience of typing two commands into two windows.

Comment: Short answer to the question: yes, there are many ways to do this on every operating system.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

This is an unabashed yes.

When one uses `ssh` to execute a command on a remote server it performs some kind of fancy internal input/output redirection. In fact, I find this to be one of the subtly nicer features of OpenSSH. Specifically, if you use `ssh` to execute an arbitrary command on a remote system, then ssh will map `STDIN` and `STDOUT` to that of the command being executed.

For the purposes of an example, let's assume you want to create a backup tarball, but don't want to, or can't, store it locally. Let's have a gander at this syntax:

```
$ tar -cf - /path/to/backup/dir | ssh remotehost "cat - > backupfile.tar"
```

We're creating a tarball, and writing it to `STDOUT`, normal stuff. Since we're using ssh to execute a remote command, STDIN gets mapped to the `STDIN` of `cat`. Which we then redirect to a file.

Comment: That isn't any sort of "fancy internal input/output redirection" - just the plain, boring regular stuff.  ssh reads from STDIN, just like any other tool, and passes it to the remote process. :)

Comment: @DanielPittman: But it's just so much more *fun* to call it "fancy internal" garbage.

Comment: Similarly, `netcat` on both ends makes for a great simple, easy communication channel. `tar cf - /path/to/dir | nc 1.2.3.4 5000` on one server, `nc -l -p 5000 > backupfile.tar` on the other.

Comment: @MikeyB: Good point. Netcat is a clear-text protocol so be careful with sensitive data. I tend to use netcat for more specific things like network drive acquisitions (ala dd) over a local network and port scanning.

Comment: `securely` was not in the requirements :)

Comment: @MikeyB: You people what with your flying and your pants seats!

Comment: @MikeyB Add that as an answer! It's at least one possibility.

Comment: @jofel Add that as an answer too! I'm intrigued by `socat` - never heard of it before.

Comment: For something like this, you'd often want to use ssh -C to compress the data in transfer.

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard: Depends on your infrastructure and where the bottleneck is. A few days ago I was backing up about 14GB of data across a 1Gbps link. Even with two fast machines, enabling compression was 5 times slower. Without compression it was IO bound, with compression it was CPU bound.

Comment: Yes, in some situations it will be slower.

Answer (score 32):

A convenient way of piping data between hosts when you don't need to worry about security over the wire is using `netcat` on both ends on the connection.

This also lets you set them up asynchronously:

On the "receiver" (really, you'll have two-way communication, but it's easier to think of it like this), run:

```
nc -l -p 5000 > /path/to/backupfile.tar
```

And on the "sender", run:

```
tar cf - /path/to/dir | nc 1.2.3.4 5000
```

Comment: Very good to know. This is good if the physical connection is trusted like perhaps a backup network or if the connection is already tunneled.

Comment: Or if the data is something that's public anyway.

Comment: +1 netcat is an invaluable tool, especially when you don't have a ssh server running.

Answer (score 22):

A very powerful tool for creating uni- and bidirectional connections is [`socat`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/). For a short look at the possibilities, look at the examples in its [manpage](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html#EXAMPLES).

It replaces `netcat` and similar tools completely and has support for ssl encrypted connections. For beginners, it might be not simple enough, but it is at least good to know that it exists.

Comment: @WesleyDavid: To your "Update": Just for completeness, I've added to my answer that socat has SSL support, so encryption is with socat possible, too. However, ssh is in most cases the better and easier solution, so I would have chosen ScottPack's answer,too.

Answer (score 7):

## TL;DR

Things only get slightly more complicated when you have a [bastion server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastion_host) that must be used.

1. You can pass `ssh` as the command to `ssh` like so:

   - `cat local_script.sh | ssh -A usera@bastion ssh -A userb@privateserver "cat > remote_copy_of_local_script.sh; bash remote_copy_of_local_script.sh"`
2. Beware of pseudo-terminals

---

Note that the point of key importance here is that `ssh`, like most tools, just treats `stdout` and `stdin` correct by default.

However, when you start to see option like `Disable pseudo-terminal allocation.` and `Force pseudo-terminal allocation.` you may need to do a little trial and error. But, as a **general rule** you don't want to alter `tty` behavior unless you are trying to fix garbled/binary junk in a terminal emulator (what a human types in).

For example, I tend to use `-At` so that my workstation's ssh-agent gets forwarded, and so that running tmux remotely doesn't barf binary (like so `ssh -At bastion.internal tmux -L bruno attach`). And, for docker too (like so `sudo docker exec -it jenkins bash`).

However, those two `-t` flags cause some hard to track down data corruption when I try to do something like this:

```
# copy /etc/init from jenkins to /tmp/init in testjenkins running as a container
ssh -A bastion.internal \
ssh -A jenkins.internal \
sudo tar cf - -C /etc init | \
sudo docker exec -i testjenkins \
bash -c 'tar xvf - -C /tmp'

# note trailing slashes to make this oneliner more readable.
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to put your ssh public key in another host just by one command

```
ssh root@example.com 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys' < .ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Answer (score 2):

I find this to be the easiest, after setting up no password handshaking between servers for the user you are running the command as:

Uncompressed

```
tar cf - . | ssh servername "cd /path-to-dir && tar xf -"
```

Compression on the fly

```
tar czf - . | ssh servername "cd /path-to-dir && tar xzf -"
```

Comment: Using compression on the tar file is a very bad idea if your `ssh` is already configured for compression.

Comment: @Anthon Why so bad, and how would one check if ssh compression is already enabled?

Comment: @TomHale Depending on your systems speed, this might slow down the overall operation, as the second compression takes time, but is unlikely to shave of additional bytes. `Compression` could be set in any of the config files, a quick check for that is to see if `ssh -v localhost exit 2>&1 | fgrep -i compress` gives any output (AFAIK there is no option to dump the configuration as ssh has read it in).

Comment: `tar` has a `-C path` flag that works for both the `c` and `x` commands. You don't have to put a separate `cd` command in there. (But it is good to note that you can run more than a single command.)

Comment: @Bruno, `-C` is a GNU extension (though now also supported by bsdtar and schily tar)

Comment: Good point. I should have known better.

Answer (score 1):

For moving some docker images around, or VPN `.conf` files; sometimes I do this:

#### from local to remote

```
docker save alpine:latest | ssh remote-host "cat - | docker import - alpine:latest"
```

- `docker save alpine:lates` export or save file
- `ssh remote-host` ssh to remote-host
- `cat - |` read from STDIN and pipe it
- `docker import - alpine:latest` read from STDIN and save it

Then `alpine:latest` will be available on remote-host

#### from remote to local

```
docker import - getmeili/meilisearch < <(ssh remote-host docker save getmeili/meilisearch)
```

- `ssh remote-host` ssh to remote-host
- `docker save getmeili/meilisearch` run this command
- `<(CMD)` redirect the output back to STDIN
- `<` read from STDIN
- `docker import - getmeili/meilisearch` read from STDIN

Then `getmeili/meilisearch` will be available on local host.

#### from remote to another remote (by help of a local)

```
cat - < <(ssh remote-host-1 "cat /home/pf/configs/shf.conf") | ssh remote-host-2 "cat - > /tmp/shf.conf"
```

In this style, I download `shf.conf` file from the remote-host (1) and without write it to desk sent it to another remote-host (2).

```
[ remote-1 ] => [ local (mypc)] => (remote-2)
```

Actually we can omit `cat - <` and use:

```
ssh remote-host-2 "cat - > /tmp/shf.conf" < <(ssh remote-host-1 "cat /home/pf/configs/shf.conf")
```

And this also sends newline if we be prompt for password , so the third version is better:

```
ssh remote-host-1  "cat /home/pf/configs/shf.conf" | ssh remote-host-2 "cat - > /tmp/shf.conf"
```