# How to send a output of unix command from one server to another server?

Tags: shell, ssh, io-redirection

How to redirect the output of a unix command from one server to another server.

I should be able to send the unix command's output from server-1. Then I should be able to receive the output in Server-2 and write it into a file.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34273/can-i-pipe-stdout-on-one-server-to-stdin-on-another-server

Answer (score 26):

General, you can always do:

```
<command> | ssh user@remote-server "cat > output.txt"
```

It saves output of `<command>` to `output.txt` file in remote server.

In your case, on Server-1:

```
echo "qwerty" | ssh user@Server-2 "cat > output.txt"
```

If two servers have no connectivity, but you can ssh to both servers, then from local machine, you can do:

```
ssh user@Server-1 "<command>" | ssh user@Server-2 "cat > output.txt"
```

Comment: I tried and I am getting timed out connection error.. I think there is no connectivity between two servers.. Is there any other way??

Comment: @vinod: It's the connectivity problem from two server, you can not do this if two servers have no connectivity. Make sure you can ssh from Server-1 to Server-2. Can you ssh from local machine to both servers?

Comment: yes... I can ssh both the servers separately from local machine

Answer (score 6):

You can run:

`ssh remote_server "command" > file_on_local_host.txt`

or use the output as an input for local command:

`ssh remote_server "remote_command" | local_command`

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't connect directly from server 1 to server 2 you can use this, having your local machine in the middle:

```
ssh server1 command | ssh server2 "cat > output.txt"
```